# SpriteKit: Which SKFieldNode to use for repulsion, as in an explosion?

Tags: sprite-kit

I have some ball-shaped sprites that bounce around the scene (via `physicsBody`), sometimes hitting a bomb.

I want the balls to be thrown outward from the bomb, as if by an explosion.

**What's the best `SKFieldNode` to use for this explosion effect? Or is `SKFieldNode` not the best way to accomplish this?**

I tried `SKFieldNode.magneticField()`, but it didn't give me the results I'm looking for.

Here's an example of what I've tried:

The field:

```
let field = SKFieldNode.magneticField()
field.region = SKRegion(radius: Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.40))
field.falloff = 1
field.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.explosionField.rawValue
            
bombNode?.addChild(field)
```

The balls:

```
ballNode.physicsBody?.charge = -1.0
```

But with this setup, the balls are repelled in strange, unexpected ways rather than the nice explosion effect I'm looking for.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Whether a field node will give you a visual effect that you like is only answerable by you, but you probably want `electricField`.

Comment: @bg2b That works! If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a radial repulsive force, you probably want to use `electricField`.